# Use explictely variable name (string) previously defined dynaically with exec()

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a Python function that takes a dictionnary as input and creates variables dynamically from this dictionnary using exec() function.

I do that so the function is generic and can accept any inputs (variables are coming from measurement database and one might need more or less variables from the DB).

Later in the function (for some reasons), I want to explicitelly use the dynamically-defined variables, i.e. using their names directly as string in the code.

It behaves strangely I find, I must be missing something.
For instance, if I stop the execution with a breaking point before the line where the variable is used explicitelly ("print(bbb)" below), it runs OK. I can then execute the line using 'F9'. I can also check that the variable is defined in locals(), and it appears in the Spyder 'Variable explorer' on the right.
But if I run the full code or ask to continue the stoppped-at-breaking-point code until a next breaking point, I get a NameError: name 'bbb' is not defined.

Could anybody help me here?

I am using: Python 3.7.10 with IDE Spyder 5.1.5

Best, Nicolas

Example code below:

```
def function_(input_dict):   
    string = input_dict['aaa'] + " = 5"   # Working on 'bbb' variable
    exec(string)
    print(input_dict['aaa'] in locals())   # Prints True
    print(bbb)   # I have a red cross on the left ("Undefined name 'bbb' (pyflakes E)")
    
input_dict = {'aaa': 'bbb'}
function_(input_dict)
```

Comment: "*I have a Python function that […] creates variables dynamically from this dictionnary using exec() function*" -> this is a red flag. You should never create variables dynamically. What exactly are you trying to do? There is almost certainly a better solution to what you're trying to do.

Comment: If you already have all of your "dynamic variables" neatly stored as key-value pairs in a dict, why not simply use the dict? That would solve many problems and avoid creating a lot of them...

Comment: Indeed @thierry L, i just switched to dict, cleaner

Comment: You cannot dynamically create local variables in the CPython runtime, please read the documentation for exec and check out the linked duplicate. And this is fine, since creating variables dynamically is never necessary,.and effectively always a bad design choice

Answer (score 0):

your question is a bit confusing, but from what i can tell, you can use string interpolation.

```
print(f"value of abc: {abc}")
```

or like:

```
exec(f"part of the command ... {variable}")
```

this is called an "F" string